# jQuery: Get DIV By Number (ex: document.getElementsByTagName("p")[1])

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I go about getting a "div" based on its' position in HTML.

For example, in default Javascript, you do:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("div")[5]
```

However, I can't find a way to do it in jQuery. I'd imagine it to be something like:

```
$("div")[5]
```

If it isn't possible, please tell me a way around it because I am clueless at this point.

Thanks so much, it's the last thing I need in this website I am working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementsByTagName("div")[5]` is equivalent to `$('div')[5]`

If you want the jQuery object instead of the node...

```
$('div:nth-child(6)');
```

Nth child starts on 1 versus indexes start at 0

Answer (score 0):

Try the [`.get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) function. It is much preferred. You can use the indexer however.

```
var myItem = $('div').get(5);
```

Comment: This is not working. I am trying to do: `$(".firstbox ul li." + mapi).html()` or in this case: `$(".firstbox ul li").get(mapi).html()`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the pseudo-selector :nth-child, you could also try .eq();

```
var html = $('div').eq(5).html();
```